# Curved Bottom tab in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[I have disigned using basic Bottom tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6O7L.png)

[this is the figma design which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnRxk.png)

i need to a component in tabbar in Bottom tab navigator,like below

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CurvedTabBar {...props} />}
```

i have tried to create that component with lot of svg , i couldnt,
can anyone help me out

Comment: This repo might help you: https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-curved-bottom-bar  Under the hood it uses `react-native-svg` to render a custom path